# KDE neon desktop becomes laggy after closing applications or applying settings

Tags: ubuntu, kde, opengl, hp, lag

I am using KDE neon 5.21 with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on a HP Elitebook. The system is running pretty smooth but there is one major inconvenience:

The desktop sometimes becomes extremely laggy. The mouse is still moving smoothly but every other action (moving windows, typing text, every click) takes a delay of about one second. This happens after one of the following actions (still discovering more):

- specifically when closing the application `guvcview`
- applying different window decoration style via settings
- applying different compositor settings
- adding a property to a window to force it to take a specific size

Quitting and restarting the session usually fixes the issue, but not always. I have also tested other distributions such as openSuse KDE on this machine and the issue is exactly the same.

The only thing that fixes this issue permanently is swtching the compositor from OpenGL 2.0 or 3.1 to XRender. So I think OpenGL might be the culprit somehow. I still would like to use OpenGL as it feels more smooth.

Here is the output of `inxi -G`, in case that might be helpful.

```
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics driver: i915 v: kernel 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa 
           resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz, 2560x1440~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics (CML GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 20.2.6
```

I can, of course, provide more output if desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since one of the latest updates - unfortunately I don't know which one exactly did the trick - the issue seems to be gone. My compositor is set to OpenGL and the lagging cannot be reproduced anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem. I'm running a fresh install of KDE Neon 5.21 on a System76 Darter Pro, having just switched over in the past few days from Pop OS with Gnome. Every once in a while it goes into this mode where there is a significant lag with mouse clicks and keyboard entries, etc. For example if I click the super key to bring up the application menu there is a 1-2 second delay before it comes up. Or if I'm typing a password I'll get two or three characters in before anything shows up on the screen. It's very frustrating and difficult to work with.

In contrast to you, however, I've never had this problem on this machine when I used another distro (although the only other one I tried is Pop, which came with installed on the machine). The other thing I should note is that before I put Neon on this machine I played around with it on an old Dell Latitude 6420 and did not encounter this problem in many hours of use. Other than the difference between the machines, the only difference there is that I didn't use full disk encryption in that install, while I did on my System76 machine. Don't know if the encryption is involved, but I thought I should mention it in case it is.

Your question, however, and your guess about OpenGL being involved, inspired me to try switching to a Wayland session, which (so far) seems to have solved the problem. I'd like to stick with Wayland anyway, which I did with minimal issues while I was on Gnome, so we'll see how it goes with Plasma.

Comment: Using Wayland does solve this issue partly for me. After, for example, applying attributes to windows the desktop is laggy again. Also Wayland breaks parts of my setup so I don't want to use it right now. But I'm glad you found a solution.

Comment: I haven't had it slow down again since switching to Wayland, but I have noticed plenty of other problems that weren't there when I was on X, so I just switched back.